# How to change JDK versions on Windows

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to change my Java jdk from jdk `1.7.0_51` to `1.8.0_65` but I'm running into issues.

I successfully install the jdk and change JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65` but when I run `javac -version` it still displays `1.7.0_51` as the current version.

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Oracle\Ora‌​11g\bin;C:\Program Files\MKS\IntegrityClient2009\bin;C:\Windows\system32;...` I already added JAVA_HOME to the beginning of Path

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add java.exe location to path?

Comment: As suggested above, the `PATH` should direct to the `bin` directory. Also, you will probably be using the `cmd` prompt to run the `java -version`. You  will need to close and reopen the `cmd prompt` after changing the `environment variables`.

Comment: Open a new command prompt window, and provide log for following 2 commands - `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%`

Comment: @hagrawal interesting... I changed the variables but when I `echo %PATH%` it's still pointing to `jdk1.7.0_51`

Comment: Can you paste actual log values of both commands ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to path.

Make sure you open a new console when you check again, because the changes will not apply in a console opened before setting the environment variable.